# Can I change Outlook International Options via vCard?

Tags: utf-8, outlook, coldfusion, vcf-vcard

I am using coldFusion to write a vCard file. However, there is one employee has Turkish name and there is a special character `Ş` in his first name.

In my code, I added `charset=UTF-8`, when I open up the new generated vcard in Notepad++, everything looks good, however, when I import the vcard to Outlook, I need to change the `international options` to `UTF-8` in order to import the special name correctly.

But I cannot change everyone's outlook setting from their computers, there are hundreds of computers in our company.

Is it possible that I can change the international options or make outlook understand `UTF-8` charset

Comment: Have you tried using `CHARSET=windows-1252` as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9222600/1636917 ? (Assuming these are Windows machines)